# Project Euler Largest Prime Factor bug in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and struggling mightily to understand why this doesn't work.

```js
function largestPrimeFactor(num) {
  var primeFactors = [];
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    // check if iter i is prime
    if (checkIfPrime(i)) {
      // if so, see if its a factor of num
      while (num % i === 0) {
        num /= i;
        primeFactors.push(i);
        console.log(primeFactors);
        console.log(num);
      }
    }
    if (num === 1) {
      // return Math.max.apply(Math, primeFactors) 
      console.log(primeFactors);
      console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, primeFactors));
    }
  }
}

function checkIfPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(largestPrimeFactor(13195));
```

The final console.log never goes off for the last prime number 29. I never enter the last `if(num === 1)` case either, which I also don't know why...

When I iterate up to 29, `checkIfPrime(i)` should be `true`, and then after `29 / 29` sets `num` to 1, the last `if` case should work too.

Why is this not working??

Second Q - is

```
return Math.max.apply(Math, primeFactors)
```

the right way to return the max value from an array of integers?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask **one** question per question. (The answer to your second question is: Yes, that's fine.)

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you need to use Math.max ... `i` and `primeFactors.pop()` will both be 29 at that point

Comment: but why would you want to calculate all prime factors if you need just the last one .. I am curious how long that would take for 600851475143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i = 2; i < num; i++) { // line 3
```

So if `num` is 29, `i` can only go to 28. Should change the `<` to `<=`.

Comment: this exactly matches the issue I'm having - updating to <= makes it all work.